# Javascript function does not return/exit

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

can someone explain to me why this recursive function does not exit at return. Thanks in advance.

```js
var numberArr = [5,4,3,2];

function  findCommon(x) {    
  x += numberArr[0];  
  for (var i = 1; i < numberArr.length; i++) {
    if((x % numberArr[i]) === 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
       findCommon(x);
    }    
  }
  console.log("done " + x);
  return x;
}

findCommon(0);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "doesn't exit on return".

Comment: This will run into infinte loop...you are always comparing only with the first element

Comment: what is your base condition...till when you want to run it

Comment: @Geeky  Basically, I want the function to run till it exits the for loop. That happens when x it divisible (remainder 0) by all the array elements after index 0 -- in this case x = 60. If you look at the code, when it "console logs" it should return and exit the function, because the very next line after "console.log" is "return x".

Comment: @Yas It *does* exit the function when the `return` statement is reached, but it does only exit the *current invocation*. It then keeps continuing where `findCommon(x)` was called.

Comment: @Bergi Based on what you said, I moved my "return" call right after the recursive call back. And it worked! The function terminated when I wanted it to, but the returned x reverted back to it's original value. So i had to create a global var to store the x value in and return that global var instead - very messy it think. Cloud I have done this differently using the same approch.
I'll post the code below.

Comment: @Yas Instead of doing `findCommon(x); return x;` use `return findCommon(x);` - no need for global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try abouve code.. it is so tricky what is happening to your code. actually your function `findcommon(x)` is calling itself and what is happening is it run the function currently in and the function that calls. it means if we call  `findcommon(x)` one time then it wont break from the current will not end. it completes both functions one by one.

```
var numberArr = [5,4,3,2];

function  findCommon(x) {    
  x += numberArr[0];  
  for (var i = 1; i < numberArr.length; i++) 
  {
    if((x % numberArr[i]) === 0) 
    {
      continue;
    } 
    else 
    {
       findCommon(x);
    }    
  }
  console.log("done " + x);
  return x;
}
//findCommon(3);
console.log("done " +findCommon(3));
```

eg : if i call function B from function A it will complete Both B and A
like that your function findCommon(x); calls it self so many times. that is why it comes in recursive.hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exit at the return, as you can see if you modify it slightly to show you some more information.

```js
var numberArr = [5,4,3,2];

function  findCommon(x) {    
  x += numberArr[0];  
  for (var i = 1; i < numberArr.length; i++) {
    if((x % numberArr[i]) === 0) {
      console.log("Continuing: " + i)
      continue;
    } else {
      console.log("B: " + findCommon(x))
    }    
  }
  console.log("done " + x);
  return x;
}

console.log("A: " + findCommon(0));
```

Comment: after my console log "done 60" it should hit "return x" and terminate, but it keeps on going.

Answer (score 0):

I achived my purpose with the code below. Any suggestions on how I could have avoided returning a global var or another ways I could have done this.

```js
var numberArr = [5,4,3,2];
var y;

function  findCommon(x) {    
  x += numberArr[0];  
  for (var i = 1; i < numberArr.length; i++) {
    if((x % numberArr[i]) === 0) {
      console.log("continue " + x);
      continue;
    } else {
       console.log("not div " + x);
       findCommon(x);
       return y;
    }    
  }
  y = x;
  console.log("done " + x);
}

findCommon(0);
```